# Pandas Transform Position/Rank in Group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following `DataFrame` with two groups of animals and how much food they eat each day,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animals': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'rat', 
                               'cat', 'rat', 'rat', 'dog', 'cat'],
                   'food': [1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 0, 6, 5]},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['group1'] + ['group2'],
                                                    list(range(5))])
                     ).rename_axis(['groups', 'day'])

df

            animals food
groups  day     
group1  0   cat     1
        1   cat     2
        2   dog     2
        3   dog     5
        4   rat     3
group2  0   cat     1
        1   rat     4
        2   rat     0
        3   dog     6
        4   cat     5
```

I can "map"/transform this into a new column to see how much food each individual animal should be given per day `daily_meal`.

```
df['daily_meal'] = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups']).transform('mean')
df

            animals food    daily_meal
groups  day         
group1  0   cat     1       1.5
        1   cat     2       1.5
        2   dog     2       3.5
        3   dog     5       3.5
        4   rat     3       3.0
group2  0   cat     1       3.0
        1   rat     4       2.0
        2   rat     0       2.0
        3   dog     6       6.0
        4   cat     5       3.0
```

I now wish to know where that daily_meal ranks within each group, and "map"/transform this into a new column called `group_rank`. How can I do this?

e.g.

```
            animals food    daily_meal   group_rank
groups  day         
group1  0   cat     1       1.5          1
        1   cat     2       1.5          1
        2   dog     2       3.5          3
        3   dog     5       3.5          3
        4   rat     3       3.0          2

group2  0   cat     1       3.0          2
        1   rat     4       2.0          1
        2   rat     0       2.0          1
        3   dog     6       6.0          3
        4   cat     5       3.0          2
```

Comment: @stucash are you using pandas 0.21?

Comment: oops, sorry you are right.

Comment: I guess I should leave a trace here rather than deleting it, I was not able to run `df['daily_meal'] = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups']).transform('mean')` in pandas 0.18 which is probably a bit old...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use double [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['daily_meal'] = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups'])['food'].transform('mean')
df['group_rank'] = df.groupby('groups')['daily_meal'].rank(method='dense')
print (df)
           animals  food  daily_meal  group_rank
groups day                                      
group1 0       cat     1         1.5         1.0
       1       cat     2         1.5         1.0
       2       dog     2         3.5         3.0
       3       dog     5         3.5         3.0
       4       rat     3         3.0         2.0
group2 0       cat     1         3.0         2.0
       1       rat     4         2.0         1.0
       2       rat     0         2.0         1.0
       3       dog     6         6.0         3.0
       4       cat     5         3.0         2.0
```

Or:

```
s = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups'])['food'].transform('mean')
df['group_rank'] = s.groupby('groups').transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense'))
print (df)
           animals  food  group_rank
groups day                          
group1 0       cat     1         1.0
       1       cat     2         1.0
       2       dog     2         3.0
       3       dog     5         3.0
       4       rat     3         2.0
group2 0       cat     1         2.0
       1       rat     4         1.0
       2       rat     0         1.0
       3       dog     6         3.0
       4       cat     5         2.0
```

Thanks [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775927/pandas-transform-position-rank-in-group/47776077#comment82513404_47776077) for improving solution:

```
df['daily_meal'] = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups'])['food'].transform('mean')
df['group_rank'] = df.groupby('groups')['daily_meal'].rank(method='dense')
```

---

```
s = df.groupby(['animals', 'groups'])['food'].transform('mean')
df['group_rank'] = s.groupby('groups').rank(method='dense')
```

Comment: I am curious to know the way you thought before you arrived at this solution...and also your edits...Is it just experience with pandas or statistical knowledge?...

Comment: More first, statistics is hard for me ;)

Comment: Why not? `df.groupby(level=0)['daily_meal'].rank(method='dense')` or `df.groupby('groups')['daily_meal'].rank(method='dense')`

Comment: Something between ;)

Comment: I have a question , the first version of yours is very similar with mine right ?

Comment: Yes, it is similar, @Wen

Comment: @ScottBoston - Why does `groupby` work without `transform`? Isn't the whole idea of transform to return something the same size/index as the original DataFrame? `groupby` is meant to return an aggregation?

Comment: But I dont copy your solution, I use transform too (because transform(`mean`) )

Comment: It is fine , just make sure , take it easy :-)

Comment: @josh You need `groupby` because you are ranking with a group and not the complete dataframe.

Comment: @josh - I think it working without transform also because it return Series with same size as groups sizes - data are not aggregate like `mean`

Comment: Thank you both. I though groupby's always reduced. Back to the Pandas docs for me!

Answer (score 3):

Using `get_level_values` + `transform` + `rank`

```
df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(level='groups')])['daily_meal '].apply(lambda x : x.rank(method ='dense'))
Out[1068]: 
groups  day
group1  0      1.0
        1      1.0
        2      3.0
        3      3.0
        4      2.0
group2  0      2.0
        1      1.0
        2      1.0
        3      3.0
        4      2.0
Name: daily_meal , dtype: float64
```

After assign

```
df['group_rank']=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(level='groups')])['daily_meal '].apply(lambda x : x.rank(method ='dense'))
df
Out[1070]: 
           animals  food  daily_meal   group_rank
groups day                                       
group1 0       cat     1          1.5         1.0
       1       cat     2          1.5         1.0
       2       dog     2          3.5         3.0
       3       dog     5          3.5         3.0
       4       rat     3          3.0         2.0
group2 0       cat     1          3.0         2.0
       1       rat     4          2.0         1.0
       2       rat     0          2.0         1.0
       3       dog     6          6.0         3.0
       4       cat     5          3.0         2.0
```

Here is the method I get the `daily_meal`

```
df['daily_meal ']=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(level='groups'),df.animals])['food'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: great solution and you got in there very quickly. jezrael's answer is a little more terse and is more pandas 0.21 as omits the `df.index.get_level_values`. Thanks :)

Comment: @josh ok :-) ,happy coding

Comment: @josh the reason why i using get_index_level is because stucash's question in your comment

Comment: yes, your answer is probably better for anyone pre-0.21. My favourite new thing about 0.21 is this combined col-index groupby functionality as it saves you this extra work :)