# Pandas ffill limit groups of nan less than limit only

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I wish to forward fill some values in my pandas dataframe, with a limit. However, the limit needs to only fill groups of nans where the continuous nan count is less than or equal to the limit. Here is an example,

Create a df with missing data,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'val': [1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1]}
)

print(df)

    val
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    1.0
11    1.0
```

Now if we ffill it fills all nans up to 2 steps forwards,

```
print(df.ffill(limit=2))

    val
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     3.0 #
7     3.0 #
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    1.0
11    1.0
```

Those reads (above) with # fill when I do not want them to. What I would like is to get the following,

```
print(df.ffill(limit=2, dont_fill_any_nan_gaps_bigger_than_limit=True))

    val
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     NaN # 
7     NaN #
8     NaN 
9     NaN 
10    1.0
11    1.0
```

Of course this does not need to be a single parameter in `ffill` but something with the same effect.

Comment: Just realised that I half finished the title. I have added a title but please suggest a better one. Wasn't sure how to word it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have take inspiration from both excellent answers as well as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776077/4049396) from jezral to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775927/pandas-transform-position-rank-in-group) to apply this to the whole DataFrame.

I did this so that I could treat an entire DataFrame in one go and so that each column would `ffill` the missing values in their respective columns (with my extra constraint).

Setup a DataFrame,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'val1': [1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1],
     'val2': [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 4, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2]}
)

print(df)

    val1    val2
0   1.0     1.0
1   1.0     2.0
2   NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN
4   2.0     2.0
5   3.0     4.0
6   NaN #   4.0
7   NaN #   NaN #
8   NaN #   NaN #
9   NaN #   NaN #
10  1.0     NaN #
11  1.0     2.0
```

Now do `mask` and `ffill`,

```
mask_df = (
    df.isnull()
      .groupby([df.notnull().all(axis=1).cumsum()])
      .rank(method='max') - 1
).gt(2)

df = df.ffill().mask(mask_df)
print(df)

    val1    val2
0   1.0     1.0
1   1.0     2.0
2   1.0     2.0
3   1.0     2.0
4   2.0     2.0
5   3.0     4.0
6   NaN #   4.0
7   NaN #   NaN #
8   NaN #   NaN #
9   NaN #   NaN #
10  1.0     NaN #
11  1.0     2.0
```

**Explaination**

We `groupby` using a cumulative sum over the non-`nan` values. This means the `nan` values become grouped together. If we take the max `rank` of these we get the length of the `nan` sequence + 1. Now we just use the `mask` function as shown by cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940731/4049396).

Comment: If setting `df.iloc[9,1] = 23` this stops to work if you want to treat each column of the `df` separately. My current workaround is to define a mask function `def masker(df, limit): return (df.isna().groupby([df.notna().cumsum()]).rank(method='max') - 1).gt(limit)` and apply this function along the columns: `mask_df = df_ext.apply(masker, axis=0, args=(limit,))`. I guess this is quite slow for big dataframes. Is there any way I can do this directly without apply?

Comment: @Scotty1- I cannot understand why `df.iloc[9,1] = 23` breaks this. It might be better to treat the cause rather than the symptoms, but I am taking a look at this.

Comment: @josh `[df.notnull().all(axis=1).cumsum()]` with `axis=1` as `groupby` argument considers only rows which are all nan. But I was not able to make a vectorized approach to this, only using apply worked for me. Unluckily using this masking method with apply on medium sized dataframes is horribly slow. But honestly: I'm not good with groupby etc., thus I am quite sure that there is a better approach.

Comment: I just stopped my test-run on a df of shape `(2600000, 80)` after 45 minutes. There must be a way to vectorize this...

Comment: @Scotty1- sorry, I follow now. This is going to be tricky, but is a really good question so is worth creating a new post for it.

Comment: @josh Ok, I'll open a follow up question tomorrow and will post the link here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You may `ffill` unconditionally, provided you un-fill after using `pd.Series.mask`/`pd.Series.where`/`np.where`.

```
v = df.value.isna()  # df.value.isnull()
df = df.ffill(limit=2).mask(
     v.groupby(v.ne(v.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').gt(2)
)

    value
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    1.0
11    1.0
```

Comment: I saw `isna` was bein introduced. Is it recommended in place of `isnull`?

Comment: @josh No, they are different names but both do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I get they do the same thing. I meant to ask is it recommended to use `isna` for clarify/is `isnull` to be deprecated?

Comment: @josh For portability, use isnull, isna I think was introduced in 0.21 only. Neither is deprecated as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Create mask for filter out all rows with `NaN`s with size higher as `2` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `size` and apply `ffill` only for filtered rows with inverting condition by `~`:

```
a = df['value'].isna()
a = a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum()
m = (a.groupby(a).transform('size') > 2)
df[~m] = df[~m].ffill(limit=2)
print (df)
    value
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    1.0
11    1.0
```